# Why can't I change runlevel from 1 to 5 in my Debian 7.8?

Tags: debian

In my Debian 7.8,the runlevel can change  from 5 to 1,when entering into runlevel 1 from 5, e.g., when giving this command on the console:

```
init 5
```

INIT:switching to runlevel 5
INIT:sending processes the TERM signal
INIT:sending processes the KILL signal

Now the cursor stops there forever.  How can I fix it?
Please watch the video of my screenshot in YouTube.

```
http://youtu.be/KlZeF3YQOCo
```

Comment: I don't know what you expect with 5. The default runlevel in Debian (pre-systemd) is 2.

Comment: Oh @jordanm, Debian Wheezy uses `sysvinit`, not `systemd`.

Answer (score 3):

"It isn't safe to return from runlevel 1 to a multi-user runlevel".

```
WARNINGS

   On  a  Debian  system,  entering  runlevel 1 causes all processes to be
   killed except for kernel threads and the script that does  the  killing
   and other processes in its session.  As a consequence of this, it isn't
   safe to return from runlevel 1 to a multi-user runlevel:  daemons  that
   were  started  in runlevel S and are needed for normal operation are no
   longer running.  The system should be rebooted.
```

http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?sektion=8&query=init&apropos=0&manpath=sid&locale=en - though this link may be replaced/removed at some point due to systemd, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You may be confused about the difference between Debian and Red Hat.

On Red Hat-derived systems, runlevels 2 through 5 have a specific meaning; e.g., runlevel 3 is "text mode multi user with networking," runlevel 5 is "graphical desktop", etc.

On Debian with `sysvinit`, these runlevels have no predefined meaning. All software that ships with an init script will be enabled in *all four* of those runlevels. You can switch runlevels from 2 to 5, but unless you've done something specific to configure those runlevels differently, that won't accomplish anything.

If what you want is a graphical desktop, you don't need to switch runlevels; instead, what you need to do is to make sure the desktop you want to run is actually installed. To do that, the easiest way is to run `tasksel` as root, select the desktop you want to use, and install it.

Comment: No ,it can change between all kinds of levels in debian8.1,but it can't in debian7,i think it is a bug in debian7,there is a progress in debian8.1.

Comment: If that seems to work in Debian 8, that probably means systemd is emulating the previous behaviour of Red Hat machines. It's not a "bug" in Debian 7, it was a conscious design decision by Debian to not do so.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I can't test this (I'm not using `sysvinit` no more) but to switch `sysvinit`'s runlevel, use `telinit`, e.g. `telinit 5` - actually runlevel 5 can be start by starting your DE. Just curious, but why to switch to runlevel 1 (single user)? If you want the `tty` only, I think it's safer and more convenient to work with runlevel 3 (multiuser with networking).

Comment: telinit 5  or telini 2 can't do.

Comment: Telinit is just an alias for init. You can use `init <newlevel>` just fine.

Comment: @WouterVerhelst Thanks for the info. But do you know any way to help the OP out?

Comment: @McSinyx the other answer should answer that just fine...